# System.Numerics.Vectors version conflict

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have started to build an app with Xamarin forms.

I have updated Xamarin forms version to "5.0.0.2337", installed [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/) and  [sqlite-net-pcl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/) .

My problem is :  I do not why I have warning saying

```
/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/bin/MSBuild/Current/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5): Warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Numerics.Vectors" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
    "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was chosen because it was primary and "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was not.
    References which depend on "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/System.Numerics.Vectors.dll].
        /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/System.Numerics.Vectors.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/System.Numerics.Vectors.dll".
            System.Numerics.Vectors
    References which depend on "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [].
        /Users/k/.nuget/packages/system.memory/4.5.3/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Memory.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "/Users/k/.nuget/packages/system.memory/4.5.3/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Memory.dll".
            /Users/k/.nuget/packages/system.memory/4.5.3/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Memory.dll
            /Users/k/.nuget/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/1.8.116/lib/netstandard2.0/SQLite-net.dll
            /Users/k/Documents/Entreprise /MyApps/lf/lfwd/lfwd/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/lfwd.dll
            /Users/k/.nuget/packages/sqlitepclraw.core/2.0.4/lib/netstandard2.0/SQLitePCLRaw.core.dll
            /Users/k/.nuget/packages/sqlitepclraw.bundle_green/2.0.4/lib/Xamarin.iOS10/SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll
            /Users/k/.nuget/packages/sqlitepclraw.provider.dynamic_cdecl/2.0.4/lib/netstandard2.0/SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl.dll (MSB3277) (lfwd.iOS)
```

I have looked on some forum but without success.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem in VS 2019. I confirm, rolling back helped me. It helped me like this:
Xamarin.Essentials 1.6.0
Xamarin.Forms      5.0.0.1905
sqlite-net-pcl     1.5.231

Answer (score 0):

As the log showed, the warning was caused by the reference of the System.Numerics.Vectors's different versions.

At first, the version of the xamarin.ios framework is too low, you can update it according to the official document.

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/embedded-frameworks?tabs=windows

In addition, you can also use a lower verison of the xamarin forms and the sqlite-net-pcl nuget packages.

Finally, if the version of the your visual studio isn't 2022, you can update it to the last version. This can always solve the conflict of the package's version.

Comment: Hi. I'm facing this exact problem with VS2022. Have tried copying the desired versions of `System.Numerics.Vectors` to local nuget cache as well as MSBuild packages folder to no avail. My project fails to build due to this problem.

Comment: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040). File name: 'System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.

Comment: *(continued from last comment)...* The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040). File name: 'System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Comment: You can post a new question and show more details, I didn't know where is the two versions referenced by. @dotNET